Find $\angle BCD$

A convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ satisfies $\angle CAB= \angle ADB=30^\circ,\angle ABD=77^\circ$ and $ BC=CD.$ Find $\angle BCD$

My attempt:

Constructed the perpendicular bisector of $DB$ to meet $AD$ at $P.$ Joined $PB$ to meet $AC$ at $Q$
Did some angle chasing and obtained $\angle ACP = 17^\circ.$
Question : How do I find $\angle ACB?$

Let us construct the equilateral triangle $\Delta DBE$ on the given segment $DB$ as shown in the picture:

This introduces the point $E$. The quadrilateral $ABCE$ is cyclic because of the two $30^\circ$ angles in $A,E$. Then $DA\perp BE$, so the two arcs
$\overset\frown{BA}$,
$\overset\frown{AE}$, have the same measure. This gives:
$$
\widehat{BCA}=
\widehat{ACE}=
\widehat{ABE}=77^\circ-60^\circ=17^\circ\ .
$$
$\square$

I was wondering how you derived that $\overline {\text {AD}} \perp \overline {\text {BE}}$ from the mere fact that $\text {ABCE}$ is cyclic.

We need the remained $30^\circ$ angle from the equilateral triangle, $DA$ is angle bisector...


Due to thhis contraction $\angle BCD=60^o$ because:
$arc BD=60^o\Rightarrow arc BN=120^o\Rightarrow \angle BCD=\frac{arc BN}2=60^o$
